# Position of bootstrap-datepicker calender on the left of input

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

This is how it looks when I open:

[image]

**I want the calendar pop up on the left side of the input instead of top or bottom.**
I have tried different orientations but no luck.

Initialization of date picker

```
$(() => {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        orientation: "bottom left",
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        autoclose: true,
        defaultDate: new Date(),       
        // startDate: new Date()
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
})
```

Comment: check the property content

Comment: There is no mention of "property" in the docs